# Why does power management ignore Logitech Rumblepad 2 input in windowed mode?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, windows-7

I've discovered that my PC ignores the input from my gamepad, a Logitech Rumblepad 2 model #: G-UF13 (corded, not wireless), when I play games with the gamepad in windowed mode. My monitors are currently set to turn off after 10 minutes of inactivity, so at the 10 minute mark, bam, the screens go black, which can be kind of irritating when you're in the middle of a fight.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate Edition SP1. I have the Logitech Profiler software installed, and there are no options in the program concerning power management. I looked up the profile for the controller in my Device Manager under Human Interface Devices searching for the option to let the device wake my PC with no luck either. Am I looking in the wrong place?

[image: no power management options to be found :(]

How can I get my PC to recognize my gamepad's input? The problem does not exist in fullscreen mode for games, only windowed. Some of the games I run in windowed mode because either their resolutions are small enough to render my second monitor nigh useless when playing fullscreen or their graphics become stretched, so fullscreen isn't really a comfortable option for me.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is either wrong or outdated, on Win7 pro x64 with SP1 the device manager setting to let an usb device wake the system from powersaving is greyed out, making it impossible to set it at all.

My solution is to use, an AutoIt, or whatever your desired language is, tool that emulates mouse movement from time to time.

Comment: The option you say is disabled is the exact opposite of the option described in the answer.

Comment: then i have to correct my text to: The mentioned settings are default in actual win7 environment but aren't working either. ^^

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://www.saitek.com/uk/supp/win7sleep.html) may solve the problem, along with this [MSDN link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930312)

In short, in the device manager, you should have some USB Root. Make sure that, in their properties, on the power management tab, the option "Allow the computer to turn of the device to save power" is not activated.

To avoid that windows 7 change the option back, open the Power Option control panel, then, enter the power plan advanced settings. In the USB Settings group, you should activate the "USB Selective Suspend" setting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange @PAinstiller! When posting links as an answer, we like users no provide a description of the link, or an excerpt. The reasoning for this is that if the link ever goes dead, the question is still useful.